# Show that the Laplacian of a function $f$ is $\Delta^2 f=(\frac{n−1}{r})g'(r)+g''(r)$

Tags: vector-analysis, laplacian

The Laplacian of a function $f$ of $n$ variables $x_1,x_2,⋯,x_n$, denoted $\Delta^2 f$ is defined by

$$\Delta^2f(x_1,x_2,⋯,x_n):=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2_1} +\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2_2} +⋯+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2_n} $$

Now assume that $f$ depends only on $r$ where $r=(x^2_1,x^2_2,\ldots,x^2_n)^{1/2}$, i.e. $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=g(r)$, for some function $g$.

Show that, for  $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n≠0$,

$$\Delta^2 f=(\frac{n−1}{r})g'(r)+g''(r)$$

Comment: The Laplacian is either $\Delta$, or $-|\nabla|^2$, or with physicist notations, $\nabla^2$, but the $\Delta^2$ should be the Laplacian of the Laplacian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = g(r), \text{ where }r = \left(x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}.
$$

Then,

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = g'(r)\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_i} \Rightarrow
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2_i} = g''(r)\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_i}\right)^2 + g'(r)\frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x^2_i}, \text{ }i = 1, \ldots, n.
$$

Now, let us calculate $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_i}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x^2_i}$:

$$
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_i} = \frac{1}{2}\left(x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot2x_i = \frac{x_i}{r}, \text{ }i = 1, \ldots, n.
$$

$$
\underbrace{
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x^2_i} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{x_i}{r}\right) = \frac{1}{r} +x_i\left(-\frac{1}{r^2}\right)\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_i} = \\
&=\frac{1}{r}-\frac{x^2_i}{r^3}, \text{ }i = 1, \ldots, n.
\end{aligned}
}_\Downarrow
$$

$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2_i} = 
g''(r)\frac{x^2_i}{r^2} + 
g'(r)\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{x^2_i}{r^3}\right),\text{ }i = 1, \ldots, n.
$$

Now, let us calculate the Laplacian:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla^2f(x) &= \sum_{i = 1}^n\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2_i} = \sum_{i = 1}^n\left\{g''(r)\frac{x^2_i}{r^2}+g'(r)\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{x^2_i}{r^3}\right)\right\} = \\
&= \frac{g''(r)}{r^2}\sum_{i=1}^n x^2_i + \frac{g'(r)}{r}\sum_{i=1}^n1-\frac{g'(r)}{r^3}\sum_{i=1}^nx^2_i = \\
&= \frac{g''(r)}{r^2}\cdot r^2 + \frac{g'(r)}{r}\cdot n - \frac{g'(r)}{r^3}\cdot r^2 = \\
&= g''(r) + g'(r)\frac{n-1}{r}
\end{aligned}
$$